# C# linq : copy rows from a table to another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 2 identical tables. I want to copy some rows from the first table to the other. This is what I have done:

```
var getTemplate = (from i in dc.Templates where i.Document == tablename select i );

            foreach (var val in getTemplate)
            {
                DAL.Type qt = new DAL.Type();

                qt.col1 = val.col1;
                qt.col2 = val.col2;
                ....
            }
```

But there are many columns. Is there a way to copy the whole row at once?

Comment: Do a search for automapper. This might help you.

Comment: Any specific example with automapper?

Comment: You could start from here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper. Also this is a good link https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/1. I would start from the latter.

Comment: Be aware though, that if your source object and destination object have a lot of different properties, than automapper won't help you more than a conversion function would do. You'll still have to map every property that has a different name in your destination class then in your source class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) will work. If your columns same name, you will get rid of big workload.

You can convert like this;

```
BankViewModel bank = Mapper.Map<BankViewModel>(BankDto);
```

And your AutoMapper Initialization;

```
    public class AutoMapping
    {
        internal static void Init()
        {
             Mapper.CreateMap<BankDto, BankViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BankId))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.InstitutionBankId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InstitutionBankId));
        }
    }
```

Finally you should register your Inıtialization where Application Start in Global.asax.

```
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
         AutoMapping.Init();
     }
```

If your columns same name `Mapper.CreateMap<BankDto, BankViewModel>()`will work.

Answer (score 0):

Christos is right, automapper is pretty much made for this type of thing.  If you don't want to add the dependency to auto mapper or learn it then look at

ConvertAll().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx